# How to use cash.js TypeScript declaration?

Tags: typescript

The [cash.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/cash/) library provides TypeScript declaration `cash.d.ts`

I tried to use it in `client.ts` file, but it din't quite works:

```
/// <reference path="./cash.d.ts"/>

const $: Cash = (window as any).$
$('div') // compilation error
```

Tried another version:

```
/// <reference path="./cash.d.ts"/>

const $: CashStatic = (window as any).$
$('div') // compilation error
```

Finally I used this hack that worked:

```
/// <reference path="./cash.d.ts"/>

const $: (arg: string) => Cash = (window as any).$
$('div')
```

And it worked, but I wondering what's the proper way of using it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after checking its source code I found out how to do it

```
const $ = (window as any).$ as typeof Cash.prototype.init & CashStatic
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by declaring a variable:

```js
import type { Cash, CashStatic} from 'cash';

declare var $: typeof Cash.prototype.init & CashStatic;

$(function () {
    console.log("Hello");
})
```

This method is appropriate when not using NodeJS and loading Cash from a CDN. It will also reduce the resulting JS (the other answer will cause the output to lookup $ from the window).

Make sure you have "cash.d.ts" in your "typeRoots" folder ("typeRoots" is a property in "tsconfig.json", read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots)).

**Update:**

Instead of putting that definition in the same file, put the following in a file in your type roots (like "global.d.ts" or something):

```
import type { Cash, CashStatic } from 'cash';

declare global {
    var $: typeof Cash.prototype.init & CashStatic;
}
```

This is better than just making another module and importing it everywhere, since it reflects how Cash is a global module and prevents redundant imports. Now you can use Cash in all your files.